# Order by char column numerically

Tags: postgresql, sorting, sql-order-by

How to Sort Character column numerically.
I have a column of numbers stored as chars. When I do a ORDER BY for this column I get the following:

```
100D
131A
200
21B
30
31000A
etc.
```

There may be chance of having one Alphabet at the end.
How can I order these chars numerically? Do I need to convert something or is there already an SQL command or function for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
ORDER BY Cast(regexp_replace(yourcolumn, '[^0-9]', '', 'g') as integer)
```

Comment: HI David can u explain what happens when i write regex_replace( , , , )

Comment: In this case is replacing any non number by an empty string.
Function definition: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html.
POSIX Regular Expressions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP