# Django Casting Character as Integer Query

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a simple model similar to the model below:

```
class ServiceIncoice(MyCustomRegistrationModel):
    (...)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    (...)
```

The field number contains integer values generally. The user might want to use only numbers or alphanumerical codes.

The problem is I need to get the last value of the field number when the user wants to create a new ServiceInvoice instance and then add 1 to the last value. For example:

1. Id = 1, Number = 13
2. Id = 2, Number = 2
3. Id = 3, Number = 16

The next item should have Id = 4 and Number = 17. However when I execute

```
ServiceInvoice.objects.all().latest('number')
```

It returns 2 which isn't what I want. I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101580/how-do-i-cast-char-to-integer-while-querying-in-django-orm), [this one](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createcast.html) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587640/order-by-char-column-numerically). Anyone of them worked for me because I need the highest number of any given ServiceInvoice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The first solution is the one I needed.

Comment: Hi @meshantz I'm happy for helping you out. Could you consider marking it as useful answer? Cheers.

Comment: I voted up the question. You haven't selected a preferred answer, and you can't vote for your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

According to django docs.

Latest Returns the latest object in the table, by date, using the field_name provided as the date field.

You can do

```
qs = ServiceInvoice.objects.all().order_by('-number')[:1]
```

Comment: I tried your solution @Rizwan but it comes up with the same result. I think I need to cast number as integer because it's stored as char field (number = models.CharField). In char fields the order is like 1, 11, 111, ..., 2, 21, 211 and so on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101580/how-do-i-cast-char-to-integer-while-querying-in-django-orm) you referenced should work as long as you update the cast in your extra call to work for your database implementation. For postgresql, this should look like:

```
ServiceInvoice.objects.extra(
    {'number_as_int': "number::INTEGER"}
).latest('number_as_int')
```